# Font Problems in Java

Tags: java, fonts, truetype

### Here's my question.

I'm loading up a `ttf` font into Java, and I know it's reading it because it doesn't give me an error, but it won't REALLY read the font, because it simply presents me with a line.

Here's the code for my Screen class that uses the font:

```
public class BLANKMainMenuScreen extends JPanel {

private JButton playButton;

Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int screenWidth = d.width;
int screenHeight = d.height;

public ImageIcon greenButton = new ImageIcon("resources/menubuttons/GreenButton.png");
public ImageIcon redButton = new ImageIcon("resources/menubuttons/RedButton.png");

public BLANKMainMenuScreen() throws FontFormatException, IOException {
    setLayout(new GroupLayout(this));
    playButton = new JButton("Play!");
    playButton.setIcon(greenButton);
    playButton.setBorderPainted(false);
    playButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    playButton.setFocusPainted(false);
    playButton.setActionCommand("/mainMenuPlayButton");
    playButton.setFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("resources/font/cubic.ttf")));
    playButton.setBounds(screenWidth / 2 - 100, screenHeight / 3 - 50, 200, 100);
    playButton.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    playButton.setRolloverIcon(redButton);
    playButton.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    add(playButton);
}

public void addActionListener(JButton b, ActionListener listener) {
    b.addActionListener(listener);
}

public void removeActionListener(JButton b, ActionListener listener) {
    b.removeActionListener(listener);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
}
```

I don't know why it would be presenting me with just a line, but it is.

Answer (score 1):

[`Font#createFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont(int,%20java.io.File)) returns a font of 1pt...you should assign the result to a `Font` variable and use [`Font#deriveFont`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#deriveFont(float)) to specify a size and style